# I've waiting list ticket with status: WL3. Will it get confirmed or not?

Tags: trains, public-transport, india

I have booked 1 tickets to LTT Express and it's showing Waiting List 3 in 2nd tier. Will my ticket get confirmed and when does it get confirmed?

Comment: Hmm, imho that's a different train and a different waiting list?

Comment: What sort of a quota do you have on your ticket? If you go to the [offical PNR checking page](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html) and enter your PNR, it will also indicate the booking quota (like `GNWL`, `PQWL`, `RLWL`)

Comment: Anyways I am flagging this question as "opinion based" because no one can predict with certainity if a ticket with Indian railways will be confirmed or not. OP is encouraged to look at resources like [this site](http://indiarailinfo.com/pnr) where the PNR can be posted and users can predict the final status.

Comment: Agree with RedBaron and that's the intention of my dupe-flag @RoflcoptrException! A Q&A for any train and any waitlist status is not helpful for other users, what helps is a post that explains the waitlist system and how to check (see comment above). Also this is as unanswerable as "will I get the visa"-Qs, thus my -1